# Full swipe to delete UITableViewCell and partial swipe to show options

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with prototype cells. If you swipe any cell to their left, two options are displayed on the cell correctly. This has been done with

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
```

Now, I want to also allow users to delete a cell. I understand the best way would be to make a complete on a cell swipe in order to remove it. This means, if there swipe is not complete, options will be displayed (as it is done now), but if the swipe is complete, the cell would be removed.

What code should I add to keep the actual behavior, but also enable to remove a cell by swiping it completely?

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: Did my solution not work? Seems like an easier option than adding third party dependency to your app. Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This repo has what you want. Have a look.

https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell